# How can I partially specialize a variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to specialize my variadic template for he first type to be `double`, but don't seem to get it working.

I have read that you can't partially specialize a function, at least not in C++03, but I think that has changed in some newer version of C++.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// end recursion if no more arguments
void apply(std::function<void()> f, int)
{
    f();
}

template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
void apply(std::function<void(Head, Tail...)> f, int i) {
    auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
    {
        f(i, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
    };

    apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
}

// one of many failed attempts to specialize the template
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
void apply<double, Tail>(std::function<void(Head, Tail...)> f, int i)
{
    auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
    {
        f(777.0, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
    };

    apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
}

void foo(int a, int b, double c, int d)
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::function<void(int, int, double, int)>(foo);
    apply(f, 0);
}
```

Comment: function templates cannot be partially specialized, at all. Nothing changed in that regard. Still, you can just add an overload. Or make your template forward to a class-templates member-function, using the fact that classes can be partially specialized...

Comment: I tried adding an overload, didn't work that great.

    ```template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>```

    ```void apply(std::function<void(double, Tail...)> f, int i)```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an overload for `apply` taking a `function<void(double, Tail...)>` and an `int`, with syntax like this:

```
template <typename ...Tail>
void apply(std::function<void(double, Tail...)> f, int i)
{
    auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
    {
        f(777.0, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
    };

    apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
}
```

Here's a [**live working example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18672dca298f68bf) with some debug printing to show that the right function is being called.